# Hibernate error trying to call a stored procedure with native named queries

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm having this problem i'm can't call the stored procedure with hibernate with a generic DAO, apparently the HQL is wrong:

This is how i call the SP:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public List<Object> consultaNamedQuery(String[] args) {
            String decimalPattern = "([0-9]*)\\.([0-9]*)"; 

         session=sf.getCurrentSession();
//gets the name of the parameter
        Query q=session.getNamedQuery(args[0]);
          for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i+=2) {



          //args[i] = name of parameter - args[i+1] = value of parametro 


  if(Pattern.matches(decimalPattern, args[i+1]))
              q.setInteger(args[i], Integer.parseInt(args[i+1]));  
              else
              q.setString(args[i], args[i+1]);

          }


     System.out.println(":::"+q.toString());
     System.out.println(":::"+q.list().size());
        return q.list();
    }
```

Here is where pass the parameters to the generic DAO:

```
public JSONObject getPresenciaGas(String parametros) {
            /*
            //parametros de entrada
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(parametros);
            JSONObject datos = obj.getJSONObject("parametros");

            String region = datos.getString("region");
            int desplazamiento = datos.getInt("desplazamiento");

            */
            //json de salida con imagen de presencia de gas en sector
            JSONObject objPrincipal = new JSONObject();

            List<Object> o = new ArrayList<Object>();
        //  o = servicioGenericoCRUD.consulta("from reporte_tipologias_presencia('"+region+"',"+desplazamiento+",1)");
            o = servicioGenericoCRUD.consulta("call reporte_tipologias_presencia('Toluca',0,1)");
            System.out.println(o.size());
            try {
                    for(Object s : o){

                        //process data

                    }
```

The log:

```
    18:30:21,062 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) :::SQLQueryImpl(call reporte_gas_region(:region))

    18:30:21,066 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 
SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08006
    18:30:21,067 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 
An I/O error occured while sending to the backend.
    18:30:21,069 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/ewisemaps].[spring]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) 
Servlet.service() para servlet spring lanzó excepción: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This connection has been closed.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:822)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.commit(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:810)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.jdbcCommit(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:986)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.commit(WrappedConnection.java:757)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:112) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:180) [hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:557) [spring-orm-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757) [spring-tx-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726) [spring-tx-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478) [spring-tx-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272) [spring-tx-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) [spring-tx-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy258.consultaNamedQuery(Unknown Source)
        at com.ewisemaps.serviceImpl.ServicioCatalogoImpl.getReporteRegional(ServicioCatalogoImpl.java:142) [classes:]
        at com.ewisemaps.controller.RestFulController.getReporteGasRegional(RestFulController.java:84) [classes:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) [spring-webmvc-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749) [spring-webmvc-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690) [spring-webmvc-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83) [spring-webmvc-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945) [spring-webmvc-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876) [spring-webmvc-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961) [spring-webmvc-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863) [spring-webmvc-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837) [spring-webmvc-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:149) [spring-orm-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
```

**Edit:** Adding the definition of the class with the named query:

```
@NamedNativeQueries(  
        {  
            @NamedNativeQuery(  
            name = "reporteGasRegional",  
            query = "CALL reporte_gas_region(:region)",
            resultClass = ReporteGasRegional.class
            )  
        }  
    )  


@Entity(name="reporte_gas_regional")  
public class ReporteGasRegional   {

    @Id private int gid;
 //more variables & setter and getters
```

Comment: it looks like the stored procedure is exiting with returning results.

Comment: Where do you close the session?

Comment: @Nicholas with or without? when i try to print the size of the list the program crash there with null pointer exception

Comment: Well, I'm not sure really, but the error says `This connection has been closed` which means the server closed for some reason. I assume it's because the SP has terminated, but it could be other reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm correcting this answer.  It seems to me you have a couple of problems with the following:

```
query = "CALL reporte_gas_region(:region)",
```

1. This doesn't appear to be valid SQL - although I don't work in PostgresSQL so I may be wrong on this point.  If you're trying to get the data for this table why not just "Select * from reporte_gas_region where gid = ?1"
2. It appears you're mixing notations.  ":region" appears to be jpa query notation while you likely need to use positional notation - and then use "query.setParameter(1, theIdYouWant)"
3. If you want to use JPA then used NamedQuery rather than NamedNativeQuery and rewrite your query to "select r from ReporteGasRegional r where r.gid = :gid"  You can then set your parameter using query.setParameter("gid",yourId).

The benefit of using #3 over #2 is that you get your response back as List of ReporteGasRegional so you don't have to do a bunch of casting.  If you use #2 then you get your response as List of Object array and you have to explicitly cast each of the fields to their data types.